# Monitor logical replication using LSN

Tags: postgresql, replication, data-synchronization, postgresql-12

How do I monitor a logical replication in Postgresql 12 by seeing the lsn ?

What I have done :
Inspect some colomns on Publisher and Subscriber.

Publisher side :

`select * from pg_stat_replication;`  -- see the REPLAY_LSN

`select * from pg_replication_slots;`  -- see the CONFIRMED_FLUSH_LSN

Subscriber side :

`select * from pg_catalog.pg_stat_subscription;`  -- see the RECEIVED_LSN and LATEST_END_LSN

I make sure all the values are the same across those colomns.

Am I correct ? Or Are there any other way to see that the replication work by inspecting some parameters ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used replication on Postgres 12.

On the publisher side there are few things you can check:

```
pg_catalog.pg_publication;
pg_catalog.pg_publication_tables;
pg_current_wal_lsn();
```

I'll create a publication "test_publication" with two tables: `t_1` and `t_2`. I won't cover the prerequisites (user, roles and so on).

```
test_logical_replication=# create publication test_publication for table t_1, t_2;  
CREATE PUBLICATION  
test_logical_replication=# select * from pg_catalog.pg_publication;  
pubname      | pubowner | puballtables | pubinsert | pubupdate | pubdelete  
-----------------+----------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------  
test_publication |       10 | f            | t         | t         | t  
(1 row) 

test_logical_replication=# select * from pg_publication_tables;    
    pubname      | schemaname | tablename  
    ------------------+------------+-----------  
     test_publication | public     | t_1  
     test_publication | public     | t_2  
    (2 rows)
```

On the subscriber side:

```
test_logical_replication_subscriber=# create subscription test_subscription CONNECTION 'dbname=test_logical_replication host=XXX user=repuser' PUBLICATION test_publication;  
NOTICE:  created replication slot "test_subscription" on publisher   
CREATE SUBSCRIPTION
```

Interesting information is in the table `pg_catalog.pg_stat_subscription`.
Here the important columns are:

- `received_lsn`: Last write-ahead log location received .
- `last_msg_send_time`: send time of last message received from the publisher.
- `last_msg_receipt_time`: Receipt time of last message received from the publisher.
- `latest_end_lsn`: Last write-ahead log location reported to the publisher.
- `latest_end_time`: Time of last write-ahead log location reported to the publisher.

You have to check these columns to catch what is happening.
First, check if the two databases are in sync;

Publisher side:

```
test_logical_replication=> select pg_current_wal_lsn();  
 pg_current_wal_lsn  
--------------------  
 0/8EB83768
```

This shows the location in the WAL file where we are now, before starting a new insert.

We can check on the subscriber that at this moment the two database are in sync, because the value returned by `pg_current_wal_lsn()` on the publisher matches the value in the columns `received_lsn` and `latest_end_lsn` on the subscriber:

```
test_logical_replication_subscriber=# select received_lsn, latest_end_lsn from pg_catalog.pg_stat_subscription;  

received_lsn    | latest_end_lsn  
----------------+------------------     
 0/8EB83768     | 0/8EB83768
```

I'll add 4000 rows to table `t_1`, and see what happens on the publisher:

```
test_logical_replication=> insert into t_1 select id+1, txt||'--BB' from t_1;  
INSERT 0 4000  


test_logical_replication=> select pg_current_wal_lsn();  
 pg_current_wal_lsn
--------------------
 0/8EC4B9D0             <<< this value in increasing
(1 row)

test_logical_replication=> select pg_current_wal_lsn();
 pg_current_wal_lsn
--------------------
 0/8EC4DE78             <<< this value in increasing
(1 row)

test_logical_replication=> select pg_current_wal_lsn();
 pg_current_wal_lsn
--------------------
 0/8EC4DEB0             <<< this value in increasing
(1 row) 

test_logical_replication=> select pg_current_wal_lsn();
 pg_current_wal_lsn
--------------------
 0/8EC4DEB0            <<< same value, WAL sending has finished
(1 row)
```

Let's look how `pg_catalog.pg_stat_subscription` values change during replication on the subscriber:

```
test_logical_replication_subscriber=# select received_lsn,last_msg_send_time,last_msg_receipt_time,latest_end_lsn,latest_end_time from pg_catalog.pg_stat_subscription;
 received_lsn |      last_msg_send_time       |    last_msg_receipt_time     | latest_end_lsn |        latest_end_time  
--------------+-------------------------------+------------------------------+----------------+-------------------------------
 0/8EC4B9D0   | 2018-12-17 11:39:56.014564+01 | 2018-12-17 11:39:56.07322+01 | 0/8EC4B9D0     | 2018-12-17 11:39:56.014564+01
(1 row)  

test_logical_replication_subscriber=# select received_lsn,last_msg_send_time,last_msg_receipt_time,latest_end_lsn,latest_end_time from pg_catalog.pg_stat_subscription;
 received_lsn |      last_msg_send_time       |     last_msg_receipt_time     | latest_end_lsn |        latest_end_time
--------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------+-------------------------------
 0/8EC4BA08   | 2018-12-17 11:39:56.737101+01 | 2018-12-17 11:39:56.736303+01 | 0/8EC4BA08     | 2018-12-17 11:39:56.737101+01  
(1 row)  

test_logical_replication_subscriber=# select received_lsn,last_msg_send_time,last_msg_receipt_time,latest_end_lsn,latest_end_time from pg_catalog.pg_stat_subscription;
 received_lsn |      last_msg_send_time       |     last_msg_receipt_time     | latest_end_lsn |        latest_end_time
--------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------+-------------------------------
 0/8EC4DE78   | 2018-12-17 11:40:04.184765+01 | 2018-12-17 11:40:04.183937+01 | 0/8EC4DE78     | 2018-12-17 11:40:04.184765+01
(1 row)  

 test_logical_replication_subscriber=# select received_lsn,last_msg_send_time,last_msg_receipt_time,latest_end_lsn,latest_end_time from pg_catalog.pg_stat_subscription;
 received_lsn |      last_msg_send_time       |   last_msg_receipt_time    | latest_end_lsn |        latest_end_time
--------------+-------------------------------+----------------------------+----------------+-------------------------------
 0/8EC4DEB0   | 2018-12-17 11:40:17.153797+01 | 2018-12-17 11:40:17.153+01 | 0/8EC4DEB0     | 2018-12-17 11:40:17.153797+01
(1 row)
```

As you can see, on the subscriber the four columns shows how WAL is arriving from the publisher and how it is applied. The difference in time in the columns `last_msg_send_time` and `last_msg_receipt_time` can give information about the lag between the publisher and subscriber.
In this case, the two servers are on different subnets in the same data centre.

Take into account that the two servers I used are test servers and ARE NOT perfect in sync between them. (The subscriber server has not an NTP server configured at all).